# Error calling commit when trying to create a fragment again

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment created programmaticaly (without declare in the activity layout). But when I try to open it for the second time, the app crashes because of "**commit already called**".

**The log:**

```
01-11 04:14:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(13556): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-11 04:14:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(13556): java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called
01-11 04:14:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(13556):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:582)
01-11 04:14:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(13556):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
01-11 04:14:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(13556):    at neviat.tbf.tartarugaburguer.Activity_Shopping.openFragment(Activity_Shopping.java:235)
01-11 04:14:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(13556):    at neviat.tbf.tartarugaburguer.Activity_Shopping.onOptionsItemSelected(Activity_Shopping.java:226)
01-11 04:14:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(13556):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2548)
01-11 04:14:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(13556):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:980)
01-11 04:14:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(13556):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
01-11 04:14:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(13556):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
01-11 04:14:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(13556):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
01-11 04:14:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(13556):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.onItemClick(ListMenuPresenter.java:166)
01-11 04:14:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(13556):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
01-11 04:14:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(13556):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
01-11 04:14:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(13556):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
01-11 04:14:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(13556):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
01-11 04:14:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(13556):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-11 04:14:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(13556):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-11 04:14:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(13556):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-11 04:14:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(13556):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-11 04:14:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(13556):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 04:14:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(13556):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-11 04:14:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(13556):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-11 04:14:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(13556):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-11 04:14:41.469: E/AndroidRuntime(13556):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**In the activity - the function that create the fragment:**

```
private void openFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
    fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment, tag);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

**In the fragment - the function that close the fragment:**

```
private void finish() {
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

Comment: Instead of reusing the passed-in transaction, create a new FragmentTransaction instance...

Comment: THAAAAAANKSSSSS!!! Thank u! =DDD

Comment: Answer the question so I can mark as answered ^^

Comment: @MdAbdulGafur Can u answer the question with your comment above, just so I can mark it as answered (**accepted answer**) ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**

> Instead of reusing the passed-in transaction, create a new
>   FragmentTransaction instance.

**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not creating a new transaction that is why you getting this error.You have to start a new transaction:

```
fragTransaction = fragManager.beginTransaction();
fragTransaction.replace(R.id.old_fragment, newFragment);
fragTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragTransaction.commit();
```

Thanks.